# Router is not defined Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new with Node.js, and I am trying to create an HTTP server, but for some reason, when I try to put the router for purchase URL request, it doesn't work.

My code :

**Server.js**

```
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http"); 


function start() {
function onRequest(request, response) { 
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname; 
    console.log("Request received.");       

    route(pathname);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started;");
}

exports.start = start;
```

**Index.js**

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");

server.start(router.route);
```

**Router.js**

```
function route(pathname) {
    console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
}

exports.route = route;
```

When trying to start the server through the Node.js, it says the follow error :

> route is not defined
>
> > route(pathname);

How can I make this work ?

Comment: Thank you @George, it worked. If you want, you can put that as an answer, I will upvote and mark as the right comment.

Comment: And sorry for the mistake guys, I am new with this, and sometimes (a lot of) happens those newbie mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the `route` to the `start` function but a parameter isn't defined, you need to add one.

```
function start(route) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("Request received.");

        route(pathname);

        response.writeHead(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        });
        response.write("Hello World");
        response.end();
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started;");
}
```